# Can Express Session create identical session id with Load Balancer

Tags: node.js, session, cryptography, load-balancing, express-session

Im using 2 machines using ebs to server my website. Its written in express.js, there are 2 node servers running. And Im creating sessions using express-sessions and storing it in redis.

Is there any possibility that the 2 machines might end up creating identical session id ??

Comment: Why both of your servers should accept the request? If you using Load Balancer request should be handled only by one of your servers.

Comment: yes exactly! It will not.
My question is say User-A hits Machine-1 and Machine-1 generate one sessionID for him say sess-X.
Now User-B comes and hits Machine-2 and for him another sessionID gets generated by Machine-2 say sess-Y.

Is there any possibility that sess-X and sess-Y can be same ?
Imean can 2 machines create identical sessionID ?

Comment: There is bigger chance that end of the world comes today, because they randomly + time-base generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the hood, `express-session` uses [`uid-safe`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uid-safe) to generate the session ID, which, in turn, [should use](https://github.com/crypto-utils/uid-safe/blob/d0144cffdc345578b0138d80db3f8f9d5ddb43a0/index.js#L60) [`crypto.randomBytes`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback) if available.

This should guarantee that the UID is based on data which is secure enough to be used in cryptography, which means it should be wholly unpredictable and unreproducible under most circumstances. I would fire up a `node` process and just confirm that `crypto.randomBytes` is available.

If you want to track which process created the session ID, you could additionally use some of the `crpyto` methods which would enable you to further encode the produced UID with salts/tokens which are unique for each running process.

You might want to discuss this further more on [Cryptography SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/) for the nitty-gritty details from expert peers, but, as far as your concerned, it should be safe to use the default session ID generator in `express-session`, not just with processes running on separate machines, but even for processes running in the same environment.